# Twitter bootstrap tabs

Tags: shortcode, twitter-bootstrap

Does some know how to do shortcode for Twitter bootstrap tabs or any other tabs? I found this tutorial http://michaelwender.com/blog/2010/11/01/creating-wordpress-shortcodes-for-jquery-tools-tabs/ but it doesn't work.

thx for your time

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [`WordPress Bootstrap CSS`](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-bootstrap-css/) plugin. It seems to contain "handy shortcodes" to insert all sorts of elements.

Also check out Obenland's [`The Bootstrap`](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/the-bootstrap) WordPress theme that was released a week ago.

Comment: It seems that, the Wordperss bootstrap css has some shortcodes but, they are written in a strange way and I don't know how to extract them...